# How to add a "where class is either of the following classes" selector to an existing selector?

Tags: jquery

I have the following selector:

```
let elements = $(.class1:not(.class2,.class3) a.class4);
```

I also get a string of extra classes to check against:

```
let stringOfClasses = ".extraClass1,.extraClass2";
```

I want the original selector to match only if the items has either of the classes separated by comma. So it will find the same elements (i.e. `.class1:not(.class2,.class3) a.class4`, but also only if they have either `extraClass1` or `extraClass2`.

The following did not work:

```
let elements = $(.class1:not(.class2,.class3) a.class4).find(`${stringOfClasses}`);
```

How can I do it?

Example snippet:

```js
let extraClasses =".extraclass1,.extraclass2";

let selectorWithOutExtraClasses = $(`.myselect:not() a.item`);
let selectorWithExtraClasses = $(`.myselect:not() a.item`).find(`${extraClasses}`);

console.log(selectorWithOutExtraClasses.length);
console.log(selectorWithExtraClasses.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="myselect">
<a class="item extraclass1">item</a>
<a class="item extraclass1">item</a>
<a class="item extraclass2">item</a>
<a class="item extraclass3">item</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to pass the selector as a string, i,e `$(".class1")` instead of `$(.class1)`

Comment: It would be a good help if you provided the html that is relevant to all the selectors. Then we can tell you if you use a wrong method or what else is the problem

Comment: @johnSmith my mistake, in reality I'm using template literals, updated the post. Carsten I will try to make a working fiddle asap

Comment: `.find(\`${stringOfClasses}\`);` -> `.filter(\`${stringOfClasses}\`);`   (or just `.filter(stringOfClasses)` no need for string literal if only a single string)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I added the snippet. freedomm-m going to test it now. thank you